# Do you know why I can't access my php file on my browser but can access the folders?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, web, lamp

I have a php project and I can't acess my file when I go in my browser: `http://localhost/www/main/index.php`.

However, when I go to `http://localhost`, it displays all my folders of my project.

For information, I'm using LAMP.

The error is just that it can't find the url `http://localhost/www/main/index.php`

Here is the folder structure of my app :

[image]

Could you help me please ?

Comment: Well we can't see the folder structure of your site so we've no idea if you've typed in the right URL or not.

Comment: Sorry, I added it to my firt message

Comment: That seems to be some sort of project in an IDE, but it doesn't tell us how the folders map onto the virtual directory configuration in your apache webserver. At a _guess_, perhaps the www folder is actually at the root of your localhost and therefore the correct URL _might_ be `http://localhost/main/index.php`. P.S. In the question you said `when I go on http://localhost, it displays all my folders of my project`...it would have been a lot more helpful if you'd shown us that screenshot instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but no it's not http://localhost/main/index.php. I changed the image of the folder structure to show you this http://localhost/VetDev.info.

Comment: well that is looking at `http://localhost/VetDev.info`, not `http://localhost`! So if `www` is inside there (as per the picture), then `http://localhost/VetDev.info/www/main/index.php` ought to be the path

Comment: Yes, http://localhost/VetDev.info/www/main/index.php is the correct path. But when I go on this url I have this error in the console : GET http://localhost/VetDev.info/www/main/index.php [HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error 1ms]

Comment: Anyway, your 500 error is a different problem. 500 Internal Server Error is a generic error message informing you that the server crashed while processing the request. Beyond that, it's (intentionally) meaningless, and is of very little use for debugging. You need to check the PHP error log file on the server to try and find the underlying exception message. Once you've got that, you stand a chance of identifying the problem. If you're still stuck after that, post a new question here with full details of the relevant code and the error message.

Answer (score 1):

> However, when I go on http://localhost, it displays all my folders of my project.

As per your picture, the URL of the folder which displays all these subfolders of your project is actually `http://localhost/VetDev.info`, not `http://localhost`.

Therefore

```
http://localhost/VetDev.info/www/main/index.php
```

is the correct URL to your index file.